# Running old game build in latest Xcode 4 creates conflicts with C function in stdio.h

Tags: xcode4

I have a two year old game code which was completely written in cpp in xcode (not obj C). Now I have to run this game in latest version of Xcode 4. The game builds great with Xcode 3.2.5. But when i built the game with Xcode4, it shows following error.

`GCC 4.2 Error: Declaration of C function 'int printf(int, const char*, ...)' conflicts with in /Developer/Xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h`

`The red mark appear in line number 446 in stdio.h`

Can anyone please suggest me what is going on here? Thanks in advance. Any suggestions would be very appreciable.

Comment: Are you actually trying to build for the iphone, or for the desktop?

Comment: I am building game for the iphone. Normally Obj C is used for writing games in xcode but C and CPP is also supported. The game I have is purely written in CPP and C. And I guess it got conflict with "int printf"... but don't know where ? :(

Comment: Have you included stdio.h in your code? If so, try removing it and see what effect it has.

Comment: I tried, but no effect. It's really screwing me. One of my senior fellow also encountered it when he was trying to build old app in new Xcode4. He thinks its bug in xcode4 may be :(. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I commented this line definition in one of my type definition file:

`#define dprintf printf`

The game code built successfully. The problem was that the `printf` was also defined as `dprintf` and Xcode4's stdio.h has definition for dprintf of its own. So, it got conflict, whereas it worked well with previous version of Xcode 3.2.5.

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me out with this issue!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Xcode, but my approach to this would be to tell the compiler (gcc in this case) to output the include tree and look there for entries of stdio.h from two separate places. If you post that tree here we may be able to get to the bottom of it - I think that that is done using `-verbose` and `--trace`.

Comment: I checked the stdio.h to see if it is included in project or not and tried removing includes with stdio.h. But no help, it always go to that stdio.h file line no 446 and conflict is there. It doesn't show from where conflict arose :(

Comment: Anyway Thanks for your interest Reinderien. Happy coding :)