# Running old game build in latest Xcode 4 creates conflicts with C function in stdio.h

Tags: xcode, gcc, xcode4, compiler-errors

I have a two year old game code which was completely written in cpp in xcode (not obj C). Now I have to run this game in latest version of Xcode 4. The game builds great with Xcode 3.2.5. But when i built the game with Xcode4, it shows following error.

`GCC 4.2 Error: Declaration of C function 'int printf(int, const char*, ...)' conflicts with in /Developer/Xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h`

`The red mark appear in line number 446 in stdio.h`

Can anyone please suggest me what is going on here? Thanks in advance. Any suggestions would be very appreciable.

Comment: Anyone to answer here? Or am I asking in wrong community? :?

Comment: This is a question for regular SO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand whether your code is written in C++ (you mention cpp in your question) or in C (as would indicate the tag of your question).

Anyway, prototype of official `printf()` doesn't include an `int` as first argument, so Xcode4 has valid reasons to complain.

Comment: well there are lot of code in this game. Most file are C++ file but some C files are also included in library. Would you please take a look at stdio.h file from above path and line number 446. It's weird how here error occurred. Any more suggestions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854271/running-old-game-build-in-latest-xcode-4-creates-conflicts-with-c-function-in-std

Comment: You are right that `printf()` doesn't have first argument as `int`. I searched the whole project for that line but I can't find it. I really don't know where is that referencing happening. Anything that I should try to find out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

When I commented this line definition in one of my type definition file:

`#define dprintf printf`

The game code built successfully. The problem was that the `printf` was also defined as `dprintf` and Xcode4's stdio.h has definition for `dprintf` of its own. So, it got conflict, whereas it worked well with previous version of Xcode 3.2.5. I guess there are some changes also in Xcode library files.

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me out with this issue!!